# prepend dropdown menu with text area

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, textarea

I'd like to prepend a dropdown menu to a textarea, when I do it with a basic input text it's working but with a text area as described in this example, it's not working:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span>server file</span>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">server file</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">local file</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">url</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <textarea style="resize:none" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fvs7t5g6/1/

is it possible ?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap input groups don't support `<textarea>`s, so you'll need custom styling to create such a widget.

### References:

> [`.input-group` contains a `<textarea>`; **only text-based `<input>`s are permitted in an `.input-group`**](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E006)

> #### [Textual `<input>`s only](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)
>
> [...]
>   Avoid using `<textarea>` elements here [...]

Answer (score -1):

You need to follow the bootstrap column structure to achieve this. Below is the simple fiddle that will guide you in proper direction.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
       Your Drop down Code
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
       Your Textarea Code
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/8h72hzn7/

Comment: I just tryed within my code (your fiddle is the same code as the one I provided) but this does not allow to have the drop down and the textarea to be sticked together, does it ?